# Kann im 2. Teil eines zusammengesetzten Satzes das Personalpronomen weggelassen werden?

Tags: sentence-structure, personal-pronoun

Beispiele:

1. > Wenn du so viele Jahre in einem Beruf gearbeitet hast, wirst auch länger aushalten.
2. > Lassen Sie Putzlappen gut trocknen und wechseln sie häufig.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Nein

Richtig sind diese Sätze:

1. > Wenn du so viele Jahre in einem Beruf gearbeitet hast, wirst **du** auch länger aushalten.
2. > Lassen Sie Putzlappen gut trocknen und wechseln **Sie** sie häufig.